# Get height of embed object with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the height of object or embed code,so it fits on the page,and there should be no scroll.

```js
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
alert(clientHeight)
```

```html
<object id="myDiv" data="http://datatables.socialmediahome.com" width="100%" style="min-height:100vh">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `min-height` with `max-height`. Also it doesn't hurt to remove any default styling with CSS.

```js
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
alert(clientHeight)
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<object id="myDiv" data="http://datatables.socialmediahome.com" width="100%" style="max-height:100vh">
</object>
```

HTML

```
<object id="myDiv" data="http://datatables.socialmediahome.com" width="100%" style="max-height:100vh">
</object>
```

CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
alert(clientHeight)
```

Comment: still there is a scroll,i just want to remove this scroll,and show full height of the object.

Comment: It will give the height but it will not resolve the problem

Comment: My code works for me. Be sure to replace `min-height` with `max-height` and add the CSS I provided as well.

Comment: You could also add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS to ensure no scroll bar gets shown.

Comment: @KhiradBanu You have to increase the height and width based on the object size. Otherwise it will give you the scroll bar

Comment: @LarsPeterson Please share the fiddle.

Comment: Yes exactly,this is what i am trying,but unable to find the height of the object @SarathKumar

Comment: @KhiradBanu The fiddle is provided in my answer.

Comment: @LarsPeterson,Can you see the scroll bar ? it's visible in you fiddle as well.

Comment: There is no scroll bar on my screen. What browsers are you guys using? @KhiradBanu

Comment: @LarsPeterson I have tested it on chrome and firefox

Comment: I don't know what to say. There is no scrollbar on my screen based on the code I provided. I am using Chrome as well. @KhiradBanu

Comment: @SarathKumar I have also created a `pen` which backs my evaluation. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLobxJ